# Getting Cannot read property 'x' of null with google charts LineChart

Tags: javascript, json, charts, google-visualization

I have a google chart that keep saying Cannot read property 'x' of null when i mouse over the legend labels and i don't know why.

All the data is in json format from an ajax get and is valid json with out null values in it.

The code is something like this:

```
var dt = new google.visualization.DataTable(data[4]);

var options = {
    vAxes: { 0: { logScale: false, title: 'Cash' } },
    xAxes: { 0: { logScale: false, title: 'Months' } }
};

var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("chart_fullsite_cash"));                        chart.draw(dt, options);
```

and the json in data[4] is like this:

```
{
   "cols":[
      {
         "type":"date",
         "id":"Month",
         "label":"Month"
      },
      {
         "type":"number",
         "id":"1",
         "label":"label1"
      },
      {
         "type":"number",
         "id":"2",
         "label":"label2"
      },
      {
         "type":"number",
         "id":"3",
         "label":"label3"
      },
      {
         "type":"number",
         "id":"4",
         "label":"label4"
      },
      {
         "type":"number",
         "id":"5",
         "label":"label5"
      },
      {
         "type":"number",
         "id":"6",
         "label":"label6"
      }
   ],
   "rows":[
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"Date(2012, 7, 31)",
               "f":"Aug 2012"
            },
            {
               "v":3937.78,
               "f":"$3,937.78"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"Date(2012, 7, 31)",
               "f":"Aug 2012"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":348800,
               "f":"$348,800.00"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"Date(2012, 7, 31)",
               "f":"Aug 2012"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":4085.71,
               "f":"$4,085.71"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"Date(2012, 7, 31)",
               "f":"Aug 2012"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":2332.41,
               "f":"$2,332.41"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"Date(2012, 8, 30)",
               "f":"Sep 2012"
            },
            {
               "v":32796.06,
               "f":"$32,796.06"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"Date(2012, 8, 30)",
               "f":"Sep 2012"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":1432204.38,
               "f":"$1,432,204.38"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"Date(2012, 8, 30)",
               "f":"Sep 2012"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":30211.84,
               "f":"$30,211.84"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"Date(2012, 8, 30)",
               "f":"Sep 2012"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":26478.86,
               "f":"$26,478.86"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"Date(2012, 9, 31)",
               "f":"Oct 2012"
            },
            {
               "v":34074.92,
               "f":"$34,074.92"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"Date(2012, 9, 31)",
               "f":"Oct 2012"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":1589939.79,
               "f":"$1,589,939.79"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"Date(2012, 9, 31)",
               "f":"Oct 2012"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":52323.63,
               "f":"$52,323.63"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"Date(2012, 9, 31)",
               "f":"Oct 2012"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":33100.46,
               "f":"$33,100.46"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"Date(2012, 10, 30)",
               "f":"Nov 2012"
            },
            {
               "v":13243.12,
               "f":"$13,243.12"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"Date(2012, 10, 30)",
               "f":"Nov 2012"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":451904.1,
               "f":"$451,904.10"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"Date(2012, 10, 30)",
               "f":"Nov 2012"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":7315,
               "f":"$7,315.00"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"Date(2012, 10, 30)",
               "f":"Nov 2012"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":11641.52,
               "f":"$11,641.52"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"Date(2012, 10, 30)",
               "f":"Nov 2012"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0,
               "f":"$0.00"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"Date(2013, 2, 31)",
               "f":"Mar 2013"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":236,
               "f":"$236.00"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"Date(2013, 9, 31)",
               "f":"Oct 2013"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":1010,
               "f":"$1,010.00"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"Date(2013, 10, 30)",
               "f":"Nov 2013"
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":0
            },
            {
               "v":21216.01,
               "f":"$21,216.01"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I can't tell what's going on.. if i change the Date columnt to type String then it works fine but the graphic changes radically it's shape.

Comment: Well, you've found a bug (which I've filed). We believe it's caused by duplicate Date entries in your data. Can you tell me more about your data? Perhaps we can massage the data some so this isn't a problem.

Comment: More in what meaning?... the graphic must show in the horizontal axe dates and in the vertical axe amounts of cash. One line for each column (after the date column). I think it's because the duplicate dates and is a bug indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what is going on, but I see in your data you have multiple rows with the same date, eg:

```
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2012, 7, 31)","f":"Aug 2012"},{"v":3937.78,"f":"$3,937.78"},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2012, 7, 31)","f":"Aug 2012"},{"v":0},{"v":348800,"f":"$348,800.00"},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2012, 7, 31)","f":"Aug 2012"},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":4085.71,"f":"$4,085.71"},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2012, 7, 31)","f":"Aug 2012"},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":2332.41,"f":"$2,332.41"},{"v":0},{"v":0}]},
```

When I remove the additional rows at each date, the problem goes away.  What is your goal with using this structure?  It looks like you are trying to create columns in your chart, which you could do by using a ColumnChart (or ComboChart if you want columns and lines together).

Comment: Like i say to Jeremy Faller, i think it's a bug in google charts. Hope to found a solution for this.

Comment: It probably is a bug, but I still think there might be a better way to organize your data to get the effect you want (and as an added bonus, you would have to wait for the bug to be fixed).  What purpose does having multiple rows at the same axis value serve here?

Comment: As I said, Phoenix_uy, you're right it is a bug, and I've filed it, and we'll prioritize it for fixing. :) ASGallant has more accurately described what I was getting at. Your data is structured a little strange. If you can tell us a bit more about why the duplications, we can get to the bottom of things, and help you.

Comment: Besides is a bug i just have changed the way the data is filled in the json and now i grouped the "cash" columns by date and now i have on every "cash" data one single date and it's all ok